# Combining GLKView with UIBUtton

Tags: iphone, ios, glkit

I'm looking for a sample application that uses Apple's new GLKView object whith other UIObjects like UIButton in the same window. I was searching that from the internet and the more like post I found was[that](http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=305876#Post305876) and is not answered:

In the application I'm creating I need to use the GLKView with 2 UIButton in the same view. Depending of what Button I press I change the parameters of the GLKView. How the ViewController should handle the GLKView? Should I have a GLKViewController separate of the actual view controller to controll only the GLKView?

I tried to make my view controller inherit GLKViewController.

```
@interface ViewController : GLKViewController <GLKViewControllerDelegate, GLKViewDelegate>
```

And set up the GLKView named OpenGLView in the viewDidLoadFunction:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

EAGLContext *aContext = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];

openGlView.delegate = self;
openGlView.context = aContext;

openGlView.drawableColorFormat = GLKViewDrawableColorFormatRGBA8888;
openGlView.drawableDepthFormat = GLKViewDrawableDepthFormat16;
openGlView.drawableMultisample = GLKViewDrawableMultisample4X;

self.delegate = self;
self.preferredFramesPerSecond = 30;

glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
}
```

The build goes well but when I run the application it crash saying:

> 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[GLKViewController loadView] loaded the "2-view-5" nib but didn't get a GLKView.'

Can someone help me? I was searching an example for this but I doesn't find it

Jordi P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message you're getting means that the GLKViewController subclass, your viewController, cannot find the expected outlet to a GLKView. In IB the view property of your viewController MUST be connected to a GLKView (or subclass) to work correctly.

Comment: Can anyone give a sample code how to do this? I'm playing around with OpenGL for iOS and wanting to add UIButtons too, but can't figure out how to this properly.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Storyboard, select the view inside the GLKViewController, and set it as GLKView class.